# Passing date-time to java executor is not transformed into current date remains has a simple string

Tags: java

Java execute the following command with imput parmeters from a XML file:

```
Exec :  run() path: /
Cmd:  /data/bin/mybase -ip 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -f myresources.afp -ad /data/afp -rd /data/afp -o /data/reports/`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`_myresources.txt
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
 <Action id="Sendbase2Job" timeout="600" AfpDir="/data/afp/" ResourceDir="/data/afp/"  LogFilename="/data/reports/\`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S\`_myresources.txt" JobName="myresources.afp" />
<Action id="JobMonitor" ProcessingInterval="10" pendTimeout="120" processTimeout="2200" />
```

My problem is that `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` is not transformed into date, it remains as it is.
I'm not allowed to modify the java code only imput XML.

When I run the command from shell works correctly.
I tried also with:

```
\`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S\`_myresources.txt but not work.
```

How to pass date/time in order to have the txt output like 20190419_110037_myresources.txt not `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`_myresources.txt?

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with Java, but rather with command line interpretation.

Comment: How is Java relevant here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by modified the Java code by adding the date in front of the filename.

```
>     Executor.setCommand("date");
>               Executor.addArg("+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S");
>               Executor.run( "data.txt" );
>               String data= Executor.waitForLine(10);
>     executorAddArguments("-o", OutputDirName + data + OutputFileName);
```

Note:My question was a little bit tricky.I looked for a possible method to do that without modifying the Java code,but seems that wasn't the case.